# Writing directly to /proc versus using sysctl -w

Tags: linux, networking, security, kernel

I am trying to configure the kernel of my Linux server so that it will not act as router, for more security. The point is not to forward packets.

I have found this:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and this:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

Obviously both do the same thing, but I am not sure what's the real difference between them. I would also like to make the effects permanent if possible.

Comment: No difference, sysctl does the same as the echo command. Just easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. The `sysctl` command on Linux writes directly to files in `/proc/sys`. This snippet from the source code for [`sysctl`](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps/source/2ec9f5c22e3eeaf4da514e0e6ec9374cfdbb9a99:sysctl.c#L351) proves it:

```c
/*
 * Write a sysctl setting
 */
static int WriteSetting(const char *setting)
{
    /* ... */

    /* used to open the file */
    tmpname = xmalloc(equals - name + 1 + strlen(PROC_PATH));
    strcpy(tmpname, PROC_PATH);
    strncat(tmpname, name, (int) (equals - name));
    tmpname[equals - name + strlen(PROC_PATH)] = 0;
    /* change . to / */
    slashdot(tmpname + strlen(PROC_PATH), '.', '/');

    /* ... */

    fp = fopen(tmpname, "w");
    /* some error checking ... */
    rc = fprintf(fp, "%s\n", value);

    /* ... */
}
```

If you want something permanent you need to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` or add a file under `/etc/sysctl.d` (e.g. `/etc/sysctl.d/99-disable-ip-forwarding.conf`) containing:

```
# Disable IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

By the way, some distributions already disable this *explicitly* by default. For example RHEL <= 6 or Fedora <= 15 have this in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

Fedora 20 doesn't disable it explictly anymore. There's not forwarding setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, `/etc/sysctl.d/` or `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/`.

Comment: Isn't forwarding *always* off by default?

Comment: That's what I think too, but you never know what wild distributions might be out there :-)

Comment: @grawity indeed, its off by default in my distribution as well. I am kinda confused now, is there any other kernel configuration in order to avoid our system running as router ?

Comment: @JohnM.: what's there to avoid if the default is disabled?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu , i dont know, i am new to Linux and all i want to disable my server from runnig as router. So i am not sure if this command is sufficient :)

Comment: It's sufficient unless you accidentally activate forwarding. If need another layer of defense you could also setup the firewall (iptables) not to forward anything, e.g. `iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP`.

Comment: @JohnM. Why do you think it *is* running as a router?

Comment: @grawity Obviously , forwarding ip packets, hehe.

Comment: Even after a reboot?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu yeps